# Need better approach to load oracle blob data into Mongodb collection using Gridfs

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, oracle, gridfs

Recently, I started working on new project where I need to transfer oracle table data into Mongodb collections.

Oracle table consists one BLOB datatype column.
I wanted to transfer oracle table blob data into Mongodb using GridFS and I even succeed, but I am unable to scale it up.

If I use same script for 10k or 50k records, Its taking very very long time.

Please suggest me, is there anywhere i can improve or is there better way to achieve my goal.

Thank you in advance.

Please find out sample code which I am using to load small amount of data

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import cx_Oracle
from  gridfs import GridFS
import pickle
import sys

client = MongoClient('localhost:27017/sample')
dbm = client.sample

db = <--oracle connection----->
cursor = db.cursor()

def get_notes_file_sys():
    return GridFS(dbm,'notes')

def save_data_in_file(fs,note,file_name):
    gridin = None
    file_ids = {}
    data_blob = pickle.dumps(note['file_content_blob'])
    del note['file_content_blob']

    gridin = fs.open_upload_stream(file_name, chunk_size_bytes=261120, metadata=note)
    gridin.write(data_blob)
    gridin.close()
    file_ids['note_id'] = gridin._id
    return file_ids

# ---------------------------Uploading files start---------------------------------------
fs = get_notes_file_sys()

query = ("""SELECT id, file_name, file_content_blob, author, created_at FROM notes fetch next 10 rows only""")
cursor.execute(query)
rows = cursor.fetchall()
col = [co[0] for co in cursor.description]
final_arr= []
for row in rows:
    data = dict(zip(col,row))
    file_name = data['file_name']
    if data["file_content_blob"] is None:
        data["file_content_blob"] = None
    else:
        # This below line is taking more time
        data["file_content_blob"] = data["file_content_blob"].read()     
    note_id =  save_data_in_file(fs,data,file_name)
    data['note_id'] = note_id
    final_arr.append(data)
dbm['notes'].bulk_insert(final_arr)
```

Answer (score 2):

Two things comes to mind:

- Don't move to Mongo. Just use Oracle's SODA document storage model: https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/soda.html Also take a look at Oracle's JSON DB service: https://blogs.oracle.com/jsondb/autonomous-json-database
- Fetch BLOBs as Bytes, which is much faster than the method you are using https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/lob_data.html#fetching-lobs-as-strings-and-bytes There is an example at https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/master/samples/ReturnLobsAsStrings.py